# How to delete old Google Urls with parameters

Tags: url, parameters, typo3

a month ago i relaunched a Website in Typo3 CMS. Before that, the site was hosted with Joomla CMS.

In Joomla Config, SEO Links were disabled, so Google indexed the Page Urls this:

> www.domain.de/index.php?com_component&itemid=123....

for example.

Now, a month later (after the Typo3 Relaunch), these Links are still visible in Google because the Urls don't return a 404-Error. That's because "index.php" also exists on Typo3 and Typo3 doesnt care about the additional query string/variables - it returns a 200 status code and shows the front page.

In Google Webmaster Tools it's possible to delete single Urls from the Google Index, but that way i have to delete about 10000 Urls manually...

My Question is: Is there a way to remove these old Urls from the Google Index?

Greetings

Answer (score 3):

With this amount of URL's there is only one sensible solution, implement the proper 404 handling in your TYPO3, or even better redirections to same content placed in TYPO3.

You can use TYPO3's handler (search for it in Install Tool > All configuration) it's called `pageNotFound_handling`, you can use options like `REDIRECT` for redirecting to some page or even `USER_FUNCTION`, which allow you to use own PHP script, check the description in the Install Tool.

You can also write a simple [condition](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSrefConditions#globalVar) in TypoScript and check if Joomla typical params exists in the URL - so that easy way you can return custom 404 page. If it's important to you to make more sophisticated condition (for an example, you want to redirect links which previously pointed to some gallery in Joomla, to new gallery in TYPO3) you can make usage of [userFunc condition](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSrefConditions#userFunc) and that would be probably best option for SEO

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Which handler do you mean? There are several of it in Install Tool, but none of them is related to the URL. And how do i write such a sample condition?

Answer (score 1):

If these urls contain an acceptable number of common indicators, you could redirect these links with a rule in your virtual host or .htaccess so that google will run into the correct error message.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes they do, most of the URLs are from one or two components... So the correct way is to check in the .htaccess for this special parameters and redirect all of them directly to my 404-page? I know how to check the URL itself, but is it possible to check the query string too?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a google chrome extension to remove urls in bulk in google webmaster tools. Check it out here: https://github.com/noitcudni/google-webmaster-tools-bulk-url-removal.

Basically, it's a glorified for loop. You put all the urls in a text file. For example, 
http://your-domain/link-1
http://your-domain/link-2

Having installed the extension as described in the README, you'll find a new "choose a file" button.

Select the file you just created. The extension reads it in, loops thru all the urls and submits them for removal.

Comment: Hi Lih, can you [edit] your answer to tell the basic idea behind your extension? Normally, answers that are just a link are deleted or converted into a comment below the question.